# SQL Giving #1055 error when using GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1055

I am trying to apply this SQL code to my MySQL databse.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( `choice` ), `choice_id`, `is_right_choice`
FROM Question_choices
GROUP BY `choice`
```

However, when I try to implement it, I get this error:

> ## 1055 - Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'Wine.Question_choices.choice_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Here is the structure and contents of my database.
[image]

[image]

I have almost no experience databasing, so I'm not really sure where to start fixing this.

Comment: Don't worry. You can start by [reading this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp). And `GROUP_CONCAT` is an aggregate function.

Comment: Show your expected output

Comment: Selecting the `is_right_choice` column is the cause of the error.  Do you see why it makes no sense to select this column when using `GROUP BY choice`?  Also, your sample data is trivial because there is only one record per choice.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't expect that query to run on both.

Comment: @jarlh a MySQL server